# accessing google calendar data

Tags: php, api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to get some basic event info from a public google calendar. In PHP it looks like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/[username]/public/basic?start-min=2014-01-01T00:00:00&start-max=2016-03-24T23:59:59');
var_dump($xml);
```

This brings back the XML data as expected, with the event data.

```
public 'id' => string 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/[username]/public/basic/k524jsujs242bag0fsqfveiij8' (length=98)
public 'published' => string '2014-01-29T21:04:51.000Z' (length=24)
public 'updated' => string '2014-01-29T22:12:20.000Z' (length=24)
public 'category' => 
object(SimpleXMLElement)[1996]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array (size=2)
      'scheme' => string 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' (length=37)
      'term' => string 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event' (length=38)
public 'title' => string 'busy' (length=4)
public 'summary' => string 'When: Thu Jan 30, 2014 11am to 12pm&nbsp;PST<br>' (length=49)
```

My problem is that in the events, none of the Titles are populated-- they all simply show "busy", even though there is a valid title saved in the actual calendar event.

Anyone know how to get the actual event title?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that the calendar, while public, wasn't set in the Google Apps admin to share ALL event data.

See here for more info: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/-YcGbl1uw5Y